# C# Nullability not deduced correctly

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, nullable-reference-types, c#-9.0

Consider:

```
#nullable enable

class Manager { 
  public int Age; 
}

class Archive {
  readonly Dictionary<string, Manager> Dict = new Dictionary<string, Manager>();

  public (bool ok, Manager? value) this[string key] {
    get {
      return Dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? (true, value) : (false, null);
    }
  }
}
```

I then try:

```
Archive archive = new Archive();
var (ok, john) = archive["John"];
if (!ok) return;
int age = john.Age; // <-- warning
```

I get a warning:

> Warning   CS8602  Dereference of a possibly null reference.

Why ? I expected that after checking for `!ok` the compiler will deduce that `john` is not null

Another thing I tried was:

```
public (bool ok, Manager value) this[string key] {
  get {
    return Dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? (true, value) : default;
  }
}
```

(removed `?` from Manager result and replaced `(false, null)` with `default`)

I now get no warning, but I also get no warning if I remove the check for `!ok`.

Is there any way to achieve what I want here - a warning **if and only if** there was no previous check for `!ok` (that is I forgot to check for it)

Thanks

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221368/discussion-on-question-by-kofifus-c-nullability-not-deduced-correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why ? I expected that after checking for !ok the compiler will deduce that john is not null

There's two reasons why this doesn't work:

1. Nullability analysis only looks at one method at a time.

When analyzing:

```cs
Archive archive = new Archive();
var (ok, john) = archive["John"];
if (!ok) return;
int age = john.Age; // <-- warning
```

the compiler can't see this method:

```cs
  public (bool ok, Manager? value) this[string key] {
    get {
      return Dict.TryGetValue(key, out var value) ? (true, value) : (false, null);
    }
  }
```

and tell that `value` is not null when `ok` is true.

2. Nullability analysis doesn't track boolean variables.

At the moment the compiler isn't smart enough to track where boolean variables come from, and update nullability based on them. For example the following doesn't warn:

```cs
M(string? str)
{
    if (string != null)
        Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
}
```

But the following equivalent code does:

```cs
M(string? str)
{
    var isNotNull = string != null;
    if (isNotNull)
        Console.WriteLine(str.Length);
}
```

> Is there any way to achieve what I want here - a warning if and only if there was no previous check for !ok (that is I forgot to check for it)

Not with tuples I'm afraid. The best way is using out parameters, although it will mean you can't use an indexer:

```cs
public bool TryGetManager(string key, [NotNullWhen(true)] Manager? manager) 
    => Dict.TryGetValue(key, out manager);
```